# Calculation of a multivariable integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I read a paper which contains a tedious calculation and end up with the following integral:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}\frac{1}{1+\|x\|^2}\frac{1}{1+\|x+y\|^2}\frac{1}{1+\|y\|^2} \, dxdy
$$

Here, $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R^2}$. The author said that this integral is easily seen to be finite. My first attempt is by integrating in polar coordinates but I could not achieve the conclusion. Any hints? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "easily." :) Don't attempt to *do* the integral. You merely want to give an estimate to be sure it converges. Ignoring the polar angles, if $r$ and $r'$ are the radial distances in the two respective $\mathbb R^2$'s, think about this: We can bound $\|x+y\|$ *below* by $\|y\|/2$ if
we know $\|y\|\ge 2\|x\|$. So our integral over $\{r'\ge 2r, r\ge R\}$ can be bounded above by
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_R^\infty\int_{2r}^\infty \frac{rr'}{(r^2)(\frac12r')^2(r'^2)}\,dr'\,dr\,,$$
which is clearly finite. I believe that with a little thought, this will suffice to argue that the integral is convergent.

Comment: Dear Ted, many thanks for your answer. I got your nice idea. Your last expression is indeed finite which, if I'm correct, equals zero. Thus, our original integral, which is clearly nonnegative, is bounded from above by zero. But, this forces its value to be zero and I feel that this is not the case.

Comment: No, no, no :) I'm looking at the stuff *outside* a huge region. Think of a one-dimensional analogue. To say that the improper integral $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,dx$ exists is to say that $\displaystyle\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_1^R \frac1{x^2}\,dx=L$, which means that $\displaystyle\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_R^\infty \frac1{x^2}\,dx=L-\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_1^R \frac1{x^2}\,dx=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.